# How to resample with interp1 in Matlab when input vectors are of different length

Tags: matlab, time-series, interpolation, sampling, resampling

I have two variables in a .mat file here:
https://www.yousendit.com/download/UW13UGhVQXA4NVVQWWNUQw

testz is a vector of cumulative distance (in meters, monotonically and regularly increasing)

testSDT is a vector of integrated (cumulative) sound wave travel time (in milliseconds) generated using the distance vector and a vector of velocities 
(there is an intermediate step of creating interval travel times)

Since velocity is a continuously variable function the resulting interval travelt times and also the integrated travel times are non integers and variable in magnitude

What I want is to resample the distance vector at regular time intervals (e.g. 1 ms, 2 ms, ..., n ms)

What makes it difficult is that the maximum travel time, 994.6659, is less than the number of samples in the 2 vectors, therefore it is not straightforward to use interp1.
i.e.:

X=testSDT    -> 1680 samples

Y=testz      -> 1680 samples

XI=[1:1:994] -> 994 samples

This is the code I've come up with. It is a working code and it is not too bad I think.

```
%% Initial chores
M=fix(max(testSDT));
L=(1:1:M);     

%% Create indices
% this loops finds the samples in the integrated travel time vector
% that are closest to integer milliseconds and their sample number
for i=1:M
  [cl(i) ind(i)] = min(abs(testSDT-L(i)));
  nearest(i) = testSDT(ind(i)); 
end

%% Remove duplicates
% this is necessary to remove duplicates in the index vector (happens in this test). 
% For example: 2.5 ms would be the closest to both 2 ms and 2 ms
[clsst,ia,ic] = unique(nearest);
idx=(ind(ia));

%% Interpolation
% this uses the index vectors to resample the depth vectors at
% integer times
newz=interp1(clsst,testz(idx),[1:1:length(idx)],'cubic')';
```

As far as I can see there is one issue with this code:
I rely on the vector idx as my XI for interpolation. Vector idx is 1 sample shorter than vector ind (one duplicate was removed).

Therefore my new times will stop one millisecond short. This is a very small issue, and duplicate are unlikely but I am wondering if anybody can think of a workaround, or of a different way to approach the problem altogether.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to extrapolate to that extra point.
you can do this is many ways, one is to add that extra point to the interp1 line. 
If you have some function you expect to follow your data you can use it by fitting it to the data and then obtaining that extra point or  with a tool like [`fnxtr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fnxtr.html).

But I have a problem understanding what you want because of the way you used the line.  The third argument you use,  `[1:1:length(idx)]`, is just the series  [1 2 3 ...], usually when interpolating, one uses some vector `x_i` of points of interest, though I doubt your points of interest happen to be the series of integers `1:length(idx)`, what you want is just `[1:length(idx) xi]`, where `xi` is that extra point x-axis value.

**EDIT:**

Instead of the loop just produce matrix forms out of `L` and `testSDT`, then matrix operation is somewhat faster in doing the `min(abs(...`:

```
  MM=ones(numel(testSDT),1)*L;
  TT=testSDT*ones(1,numel(L));
  [cl ind]=(min(abs(TT-MM)));
  nearest=testSDT(ind);
```

Comment: Thanks Natan.The goal is to get distance values at regular times (every millisecond). That happens to be the same as 1:1:length(idx). Had I been interested in resampling at every 10 milliseconds, then my points of interest would have been at 1:10:length(idx). This is typical of the intended application which is display of reflection seismic data (where distance is depth). About extrapolation: so I could just use the extrapolation option in interp1, right? Would you have approached the overall problem differently - i.e. any way to do the whole job more efficiently?

Comment: mmmmmh now that I think of it, if I use [1:length(idx) xi] as third argument, then it is again longer than the first and second arguments clsst and testz(idx)?

Comment: what's not efficient enough in your code? I could probably make it somewhat faster, but it seems decent to me... you can take out the for loop, but with the recent JIT (http://www.matlabtips.com/matlab-is-no-longer-slow-at-for-loops/) , I bet that won't change performance...

Comment: the third argument need not be equal in length, it be a scalar, a vector, or a multidimensional array, `doc interp1` and see...

Comment: that's right. OK, you are totally right. It is late night here in Norway and I must be tired. It was before I wrote the first 2 cells of code that I had that problem with first and second arguments of different length. That's why I wrote this to begin with. Thanks for your feedback about my code. I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Hi Natan, I've tried for a few days, but can't come up with a vectorized version of the foor loop. ANy suggestions? I could ask it as a new question I suppose...

Comment: WOW, thanks! I will try it, and also look up again numel, which I seldom use.